# the Firebase plugin is not installed - ionic 3

Tags: xcode, cordova, firebase, ionic3

this is the message I read in the console :

the Firebase plugin is not installed when trying to run my project on a device on Xcode.
I have recently downgraded to Firebase 4.8.0 for dependencies compatibility issues.
I made sure to add my GoogleService-info.plist to the root of my ionic project and to the Xcode project.
I checked my node_modules: @ionic-native/firebase. everything is there
There is no error. The app runs properly, excepts that the Firebase plugin does not seem to be found.
I have tried to uninstall et re-install. no success
What to do in this case?

this is my **package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "authNotificationTest",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.10",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/fcm": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/firebase": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
    "angularfire2": "5.0.0-rc.3",
    "cordova-browser": "5.0.3",
    "cordova-ios": "4.5.4",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-fcm": "^2.1.2",
    "cordova-plugin-fcm-plus": "git+https://github.com/guyromb/cordova-plugin-fcm-plus.git",
    "cordova-plugin-firebase": "^1.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.0.5",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^1.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "firebase": "^4.8.0",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.10",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.9",
    "typescript": "~2.6.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-fcm": {},
      "cordova-plugin-firebase": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {}
    }
  }
}
```

and, my **ionic info**:

```
li packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.9
    Cordova Platforms  : browser 5.0.3 ios 4.5.4
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    Node  : v9.11.1
    npm   : 6.0.0
    OS    : macOS High Sierra
    Xcode : Xcode 9.3 Build version 9E145

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : not set

Misc:

    backend : pro
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to run:-

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase
npm install --save @ionic-native/firebase
```

For more info visit:- https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase/

Comment: I did. still not working. Weird thing is that it used to work